# Разбить строку на массив

Tags: php

Например есть строка:

слово1 слово2 слово3 ...

слова отделют пробелы, как преобразовать эту строку в такой вид:

слово1
слово2
слово3
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = explode(' ', trim($str));
```

Comment: опять вы :-D

Comment: я вездесущ :D

Comment: как с тобой связаться, есть воросы по заиси массива в файл, ася если есть дай

Comment: асю не юзаю, VK и скайп в профиле

Comment: О_о Mi en el choque, por que no usas icq? Comprendes? :-)

Comment: Потому что зае... надоело вообщем в свое время